# Removing data and retrieving a random date | Watir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, watir

Given the following code.

```
<ul class="search-fields clearfix">
<li class="charter-type-search clearfix">
<li class="destination-search where clearfix">
<li class="departure-search when clearfix">
  <div class="icon-heading">
  <div class="icon-search holiday-search-fields form-type-select form-item-date">
  <select id="edit-date" class="form-select ajax-processed" name="date">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Anytime</option>
    <option value="2015-12">December 2015 (25)</option>
    <option value="2016-01">January 2016 (26)</option>
    <option value="2016-02">February 2016 (29)</option>
    <option value="2016-03">March 2016 (30)</option>
    <option value="2016-04">April 2016 (38)</option>
    <option value="2016-05">May 2016 (37)</option>
    <option value="2016-06">June 2016 (40)</option>
    <option value="2016-07">July 2016 (39)</option>
    <option value="2016-08">August 2016 (37)</option>
    <option value="2016-09">September 2016 (33)</option>
    <option value="2016-10">October 2016 (33)</option>
    <option value="2016-11">November 2016 (28)</option>
    <option value="2016-12">December 2016 (25)</option>
    <option value="2017-01">January 2017 (21)</option>
    <option value="2017-02">February 2017 (21)</option>
    <option value="2017-03">March 2017 (21)</option>
    <option value="2017-04">April 2017 (27)</option>
    <option value="2017-05">May 2017 (27)</option>
    <option value="2017-06">June 2017 (29)</option>
  </select>
```

I am using the following to retrieve a random date

`all_options = b.select_list(id: "edit-date").options`

`b.select_list(id: "edit-date").option(index: rand(all_options.size)).select`

if I wanted to remove the first 5 elements from this so (Dec15-April16) then randomly select the rest how can I do this? I am using `.drop(5)` but it still selects some of these dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference, the typical way to select from a list is by direct string:

```
b.select(id: 'edit-date').select('May 2017 (29)')
```

or regular expression

```
b.select(id: 'edit-date').select(/May 2017/)
```

All that select method is doing is locating, verifying & clicking on the element. The first two are already accomplished when you get the options list, so all you need to do from there is the click:

```
b.select(id: 'edit-date').options.drop(5).sample.click
```

Comment: Thank you so much! couldn't understand why drop(5) wasn't working.

Comment: OP: you should accept this answer if it solved your issue.